# Turn django rest framework url completely off

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Hey i was wondering if it is possible to completely turn off the `drf` own rendering url.

I know that u can switch from the browsable api renderer to the JSON renderer.
As i have it on my own settings shown below

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ]
}
```

When I go to my localhost:8000/products I want to see simply a 404 page and not the JSON rendered products. I am currently using a simple router.

Edit :

This is how it looks when I go to the url in the browser. This is the url of the back-end

https://ibb.co/717R8SM

I dont want it to display anything if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

> localhost:8000/products I want to see simply a 404 page

In any part where you want to show 404, you can do the following example:

```
# views.py
from django.http import Http404
def products(request, ):
    if request.is_ajax():
        return Response(data)
    raise Http404("Product does not exist")
```

Comment: I dont think i was very clear with my post i will update it with some pictures.

Comment: Do you want, show 404 pages? You can use `raise Http404` but if you do this, then your application does not work. If you don't want to show anything but the api is useful in webapp, you can check`if request.is_ajax` in above code.

Comment: Yeah i think the second one where request is ajax im gonna try that